# Can't delete all unused kernels

Tags: apt, kernel

I am trying to remove all my unused kernels but it is not working. My **dpkg --list | grep linux-image** result is as follows:

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                   3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.24.28                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

It is not showing any other kernel entries whereas there are many. **ls /lib/modules** gives me this result:

```
   3.13.0-24-generic  3.17.0-rc6+                3.18.0-rc1-00326-g3d85e2c-dirty
3.17.0-rc5+        3.18.0-rc1+
3.17.0-rc6         3.18.0-rc1-00314-gb0ef3ed
```

Currently I am running 3.18.0-rc1+ and I wants to remove all other 3.18.xxx versions but no command is working. I ran **sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.18.0-rc1-00326-g3d85e2c-dirty** but it is showing following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.18.0-rc1-00326-g3d85e2c-dirty
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.18.0-rc1-00326-g3d85e2c-dirty'
```

I also tried **sudo apt-get autoremove** but it is showing following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 420 not upgraded.
```

I am confused now. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those remaining folders of already purged kernels are only links to the headers/source files of those kernels.

So, you can get rid of them purging the respective headers files, like:

**sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-headers-3.18.0-rc1-00326-g3d85e2c-dirty**

Look, I suggest you to use **--purge remove** directive to clean it all up. Also, If you remove future kernel only image with **--purge remove**, you will also get ride of the /lib/modules links, even not purging the headers files.

Comment: Didn't work..Same result as **sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.18.0-rc1-00326-g3d85e2c-dirty** :(

Comment: my ls vmlinuz* gives me this result:                                                           vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic             vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc1+
vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed  vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc1-00314-gb0ef3ed
vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+                   vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc1-00314-gb0ef3ed.old
vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6                    vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc1-00326-g3d85e2c-dirty
vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc6+                   vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc1+.old

Comment: In this case I really think those files are orphans, so you can remove them manually.

Comment: Actually I was worried for other files which are linked with it. But yeah it worked. They were orphans. May be I needed someone just to say that go and remove them. Thanks :)

Comment: @user297666, if you have previously removed a package without purging it, purging it does not work. I suppose you could reinstall the package and purge it thereafter to remove all (system wide?) configuration, too.